# MapStruct : Getting error of implementation is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am new to MapStruct and I am currently doing a POC. I can see that `MapStruct` is able to generate an implementation class from interface for a general method

```
Set<String> integerSetToStringSet(Set<Integer> integers);
```

but when I use the project specific classes it gives me compilation error of `<InterfaceName>impl is not abstract and does not override the abstract method <customMethod>.`

I am using an interface with just one method. The interface is annotated with `@Mapper` but the method is simple `one-to-one` mapping with no need of `@Mapping` annotation.

As mentioned earlier, if I put a general method all works fine but not for project specific classes.

Can someone give me some pointers on this issue?

Comment: Can you share the complete definition of your mapper interface, please?